# aws s3Client PutObject Access Denied, but CyberDuck can PutObject Successfully

Tags: php, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3

Im facing a mystery on S3 bucket policy, and it is preventing my a Php S3Client from PutObject. The error im getting is:

> Error executing "PutObject" on "https://s3.amazonaws.com/reusable-system-dev/b1e42024e33d62b852d3c94c85f68c72.jpeg"; AWS HTTP error: Client error response [url] https://s3.amazonaws.com/reusable-system-dev/b1e42024e33d62b852d3c94c85f68c72.jpeg [status code] 403 [reason phrase] Forbidden AccessDenied (client): Access Denied

But, with the same Access key and Secret key, i can PutObject using a CyberDuck client!  Is there any hidden S3 policy that could cause such a strange behavior?

Comment: Are you having similar symptoms on HEAD or GET?

Answer (score 2):

I've seen this exact symptom before. The issue may be with the date/time stamp being generated by the s3client in your Php code. Turn on debugging for the s3client and see if the date/time stamp in the request is being produced with "GMT" (correct) or something else. If its something else, that could be the issue, you could compare it to CyberDuck if it will show you the debug output for the request its making.

Answer (score 1):

This may be due to wrong authentication. Make sure you are authenticating perfectly.

One way to test is try to access some restricted/private resource from S3 through s3 client.

Comment: I was hoping the same. Unfortunately, i tripple checked the access and secret key, they are all the same.  And this bucket only have private resource anyway...

Answer (score 1):

[**PutObject**:](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/API/RESTObjectPUT.html)

**Note:**

To configure your application to send the Request Headers prior to sending the request body, use the **100-continue HTTP status code**

Comment: Interesting.... I just try it, unfortunately it doesn't have any effect. im guessing the error im getting is permission issue, not authentication or redirect error

Answer (score 0):

I got the error because of CannedACL usage (requires PutObjectAcl permission).